# How to deliberately crash a COM object

Tags: c#, vb.net, com

Maybe a strange question, but I need to test the stability and error procedures of the host process (caller) that accesses COM objects. Therefore I need some easy/short methods to let the COM object(s) crash *itself*.

Addition 1: With crash I mean the type of crash that can take the caller down also.

Addition 2: I own both the code of the caller as the COM server.

Comment: Please explain. Don't know what you mean.

Comment: @Mark vB: Do you own the COM code? How does the host process bind to the COM server(s)? What do you mean by "crash"

Comment: I do own both the code of the caller as the COM server. I can manipulate the COM server/object anyway I want to achieve a crash in it. I just need a code example (preferably in VB.NET, but C# is also ok) that I can execute in the COM server to let it crash.

Comment: I've never seen anyone actually ask how TO crash a COM object before. Though I've definitely suspected that some people went out of their way to gain expertise on the subject. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you mean by "crash"? What language are you using in your COM server

- If you mean **throw an exception via COM**, then just explicitly throw an exception or raise an error. Or you could deliberately divide by zero if you like.
- If you mean **freeze up and never return**, deliberately code an infinite loop. E.g. `for(;;);`
- If you mean an **unhandled access violation**, it depends on the language you're using in your COM server. You could try to access a NULL memory location.

Comment: I want to create an access violation *in* the COM object that can/will bring the caller down. Reason for this is to have a way to test/optimize the stability measures in the caller. Therefore I need a dirty/insecure/instable COM object.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a community wiki on ways to crash programs yet?

A couple off of the top of my head:

- Cause a massive Stack Overflow :)
- Throw an exception

Comment: Yep, I know, it's an unusual question ... ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using COM to communicate with another executable (as opposed to loading a dll into your own process space), you can `taskkill` the other process from the commandline.